# In PL/SQL, How do you turn Dynamic SQL into "safe", un-dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I have some dynamic SQL code, here's a sampple:

```
    v_RUNNING_QUERY VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN
    v_RUNNING_QUERY := 'SELECT PBA.PTY_ID FROM PARTY.PARTY_BILLING_ACCOUNT PBA
                                   WHERE PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID1 = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS
                                   AND 
                                   PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD = p_PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD;
  IF p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_ID2 IS NOT NULL
   THEN 
   v_RUNNING_QUERY := v_RUNNING_QUERY || ' AND PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID2 = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_ID2';
```

The issue is that my boss wants me to remove all Dynamic SQL. In place of that, I need to mainly use IF-logic. But he also said that I can use COALESCE . I'm lost ... How does COALESCE help with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the same logic as:

```
SELECT PBA.PTY_ID
FROM PARTY.PARTY_BILLING_ACCOUNT PBA
WHERE PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID1 = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS AND 
      PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD AND
      (p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_ID2 IS NULL OR PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID2 =  p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_ID2)
```

It does seem that you want some comparison after `BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID2`.

EDIT:

You could also phrase this as:

```
SELECT PBA.PTY_ID
FROM PARTY.PARTY_BILLING_ACCOUNT PBA
WHERE PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID1 = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS AND 
      PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD = p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_CD AND
      PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID2 = coalesce(p_BILLING_ACCT_SRC_SYS_ID2, PBA.BILLING_ACCT_SRC_ID2);
```

This uses `coalesce()` but the logic doesn't *need* it.

Comment: There are indeed a lot of IF-THEN blocks after that one. But what about the COALESCE part? I'm puzzled by that